# Node.JS + Passport.SocketIO: Edit And Save `socket.handshake.user` Properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js, passport.socketio

I am using Node.JS (0.10.28), Passport.JS (0.2.0) + Passport-Google (0.3.0), and Passport.SocketIO (3.0.1).

Currently, I am able to access the user created by Passport.JS in my app's paths by using `req.user`:

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
  // send user data
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

Using Passport.SocketIO, I am also able to access the user in:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // get user data
  console.log(socket.handshake.user);

  //...
});
```

It is also possible to edit `req.user` and 'save' it by using `req._passport.session.user.property = new_property_value` in the `app.get/post/all(...)` scope. The updates then show up in `io.sockets.on(...)` user object.

My question is: Is it possible to edit and 'save' `socket.handshake.user` in the `io.sockets.on(...)` scope so that the updated user will show the changes in `req.user` in `app.get/post/all(...)`? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // rename username
  socket.handshake.user.username = 'new_username';

  //...
});

...

app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
  // send user data
  res.send(req.user); // returns {..., username: 'old_username', ...}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Socket.io-Sessions](https://github.com/jfromaniello/socket-io.sessions#change-the-session) (written by the same author who made Passport.SocketIO) to change `socket.handshake.user` in `io.sockets.on(...)`.

Code should look like this:

```
// initialization ...
// ...

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.handshake.getSession(function (err, session) {
    // socket.handshake.user is now session.passport.user

    socket.on(...) { ... }
    // ....

    // test username change
    session.passport.user.username = 'foobar';

    // save session
    //  note that you can call this anywhere in the session scope
    socket.handshake.saveSession(session, function (err) {
      if (err) { // Error saving!
        console.log('Error saving: ', err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    });
  });
});

//...

app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
  // send user data
  res.send(req.user); // returns {..., username: 'foobar', ...}
});
```